# jq unique_by - Choose remaining element

Tags: unique, grouping, jq

I'm currently trying to get a list of incidents from PagerDuty via the REST api, [which returns them in JSON array](https://v1.developer.pagerduty.com/documentation/rest/incidents/list).  I want to remove any duplicate events by using unique_by() on the incident_key. However, I want the first occurrence of the incident_key, and unique_by() is removing all but the last. Right now, if I have incident_number 849, 850, and 851, all with the same incident_key, unique_by() will return 851.

Simple example:

```
[
{ "reference_key":"200", "id":"1" },
{ "reference_key":"200", "id":"2" },
{ "reference_key":"200", "id":"3" },
{ "reference_key":"201", "id":"4" },
{ "reference_key":"201", "id":"5" },
{ "reference_key":"201", "id":"6" }
]
```

What I'm trying to do is use unique_by() to get the first occurrence of reference_key, based on the id. So in this case, I'd want the output to be

```
[
{ "reference_key":"200", "id":"1" },
{ "reference_key":"201", "id":"4" }
]
```

The problem is that I have no control over this, and with the data I'm currently trying to do this with, it is returning the last occurrence instead of the first, like so.

```
[
{ "reference_key":"200", "id":"3" },
{ "reference_key":"201", "id":"6" }
]
```

I have tried using reverse and then calling unique_by(), but I am getting the same results. Is there any way to have some control over this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe your version of jq is not sufficiently recent.  Using jq 1.5:

```
unique_by( .reference_key )
```

yields

```
[{"reference_key":"200","id":"1"},{"reference_key":"201","id":"4"}]
```

(As of January 18, 2016 (7835a72), the builtin `sort` filter is stable; prior to that, stability was platform-dependent.)

If you don't have access to a sufficiently recent version of jq, then consider the following, which has been tested with jq 1.3, 1.4 and 1.5:

```
def bucketize(f):
  reduce .[] as $x ({}; .[$x|f] += [$x] );

bucketize(.reference_key) | .[][0]
```

Or much more economically:

```
reduce .[] as $x ({};
  $x.reference_key as $key 
  | if .[$key] then . else .[$key] = $x end)
| .[]
```

Comment: I suppose my example wasn't the best since it did work this time. I'm not sure why, but with the array I'm currently getting from the PagerDuty incident list, it selects the last occurrence. Here is a diff between no unique_by and unique_by. http://i.imgur.com/3vSuoYT.png

Comment: That last section worked! Would you mind breaking it down so I can understand what exactly is going on?