# jq unique_by to choose first element after sort

Tags: json, sorting, unique, jq

I have an array of wireless access points with associated signal level.
I want to reduce this to unique SSIDs with the highest signal.

```
# cat aps.json 
{
 "AP" : [
  { "SSID"  : "Bart",   "Signal" : -20 },
  { "SSID"  : "Lisa",   "Signal" : -19 },
  { "SSID"  : "Homer",  "Signal" : -91 },
  { "SSID"  : "Homer",  "Signal" : -92 },
  { "SSID"  : "Lisa",   "Signal" : -92 },
  { "SSID"  : "Lisa",   "Signal" : -21 },
  { "SSID"  : "Homer",  "Signal" : -90 },
  { "SSID"  : "Bart",   "Signal" : -21 },
  { "SSID"  : "Bart",   "Signal" : -22 }
  ]
}
```

I tried sorting by Signal using sort_by, which seems to not know about negative numbers. I used reverse to put the least negative number first. Then unique_by seems to not choose the first element.

```
# jq '.AP | sort_by(.Signal) | reverse | unique_by(.SSID)' aps.json        
[
  {
    "SSID": "Bart",
    "Signal": -22
  },
  {
    "SSID": "Homer",
    "Signal": -92
  },
  {
    "SSID": "Lisa",
    "Signal": -19
  }
]
```

Seems to have choosen the last Bart, Second Homer and First Lisa in the stream.

The answer to this
[jq unique_by - Choose remaining element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40877513/jq-unique-by-choose-remaining-element) seems to imply this was fixed in later versions of jq, or at least 1.5, but I'm running 1.5

```
# jq --version
jq-1.5
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is unique_by() does a pre-sort before selecting the elements. i.e. it was resorting the incoming the data I had just sorted.

The answer is to present the data pre-sorted to unique_by().

The last piece of the puzzle was to remove the reverse since sort_by can negate field.

This seemed to do the trick.

```
# jq '.AP | sort_by(.SSID,-.Signal)| unique_by(.SSID)' aps.json 
[
  {
    "SSID": "Bart",
    "Signal": -20
  },
  {
    "SSID": "Homer",
    "Signal": -90
  },
  {
    "SSID": "Lisa",
    "Signal": -19
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution can be found by grouping by .SSID first, and then using `max_by`:

```
[.AP
 | group_by(.SSID)
 | .[]
 | max_by(.Signal)]
```

### sort-free solution

Unfortunately, the built-in `group_by` involves a sort, but by replacing `group_by` by a sort-free version, the above approach easily yields a sort-free solution:

```
# NOTE: it is assumed that (stream|f) is a stream of strings
def GROUPS_BY(stream; f):
  reduce stream as $x ({}; .[$x|f] += [$x] ) | .[] ;

[GROUPS_BY(.AP[]; .SSID)
 | max_by(.Signal)]
```

(`GROUPS_BY` as defined here is so-named because it is stream-oriented.)

### A note on `sort_by`

Regarding the comment in the Q that:

> sort_by ... seems to not know about negative numbers

Fortunately, the sorting filters in all versions of jq sort numbers correctly, e.g.

```
jq -c sort <<< '[-1,-2,2,1]'
[-2,-1,1,2]
```

There was, however, an important change to the implementation of the sorting functions:

> As of January 18, 2016 (7835a72), the builtin sort filter is stable; prior to that, stability was platform-dependent.

This means that the sorting filters should be stable on all platforms in jq 1.6.

Comment: I was aiming for clarity - each step on its own line.

Comment: Thanks. The sorting of negative numbers does work, I just needed them in the reverse order.

Comment: @Colin - It's best to avoid sorting, but to obtain the max of a sorted (non-descending) array, simply take the last element: `.[-1]`